# Creating NSImage from CGImageRef causes image pixel size to double

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage, cgimageref

`capture` is a `CGImageRef` returned from a call to `CGWindowListCreateImage()`. When I try to turn it into an `NSImage` directly via `initWithCGImage:size:` it mysteriously doubles in size. If I instead manually create an `NSBitmapImageRep` from `capture` and then add it to an empty `NSImage` everything works ok.

My hardware setup is a retina MBP + non-retina external display. The capture is taking place on the non-retina screen.

```
NSLog(@"capture image size: %d %d", CGImageGetWidth(capture), CGImageGetHeight(capture));
NSLog(@"logical image size: %f %f", viewRect.size.width, viewRect.size.height);

NSBitmapImageRep *debugRep;
NSImage *image;

//
// Create NSImage directly

image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithCGImage:capture size:NSSizeFromCGSize(viewRect.size)];

debugRep = [[image representations] objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"pixel size, NSImage direct: %d %d", debugRep.pixelsWide, debugRep.pixelsHigh);

//
// Create representation manually

NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCGImage:capture];
image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:NSSizeFromCGSize(viewRect.size)];
[image addRepresentation:imageRep];
[imageRep release];

debugRep = [[image representations] objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"pixel size, NSImage + manual representation: %d %d", debugRep.pixelsWide, debugRep.pixelsHigh);
```

Log output:

```
capture image size: 356 262
logical image size: 356.000000 262.000000
pixel size, NSImage direct: 712 524
pixel size, NSImage + manual representation: 356 262
```

Is this expected behaviour?

Comment: It seems like you have retina image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/initWithCGImage:size:) for `initWithCGImage:size:` states:

> You should not assume anything about the image, other than that
>   drawing it is equivalent to drawing the `CGImage`.

In the end I just continued on working with `NSBitmapImageRep` instances directly.